C# WPF "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request" error
I created an application that was receiving data from a SerialPort and was working with it. It worked for an year or two and a few days ago I tried to reopen it and for some reason, it is throwing me the error that I put on the title.
I tried a few good hours to debug and I found out that the error comes from "mySerialPort.BaseStream.EndRead". I cannot find any answer, so I tried creating a small project to try to create it from scratch. It still gives the error:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace InfoCOM
{ 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool isListening = false;
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM4");
        string resultString;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void stopButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isListening)
            {
                mySerialPort.Close();
                File.WriteAllText("text.txt", resultString);
                MessageBox.Show("text written in text.txt");
                resultString = "";
            }
        }


        private void Listen()
        {
            if (!mySerialPort.IsOpen || !isListening) return;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
            mySerialPort.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ar =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (mySerialPort.IsOpen && isListening)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = mySerialPort.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
                        if (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] received = new byte[bytesRead];
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, received, 0, bytesRead);
                            string receivedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received);

                            resultString += receivedData;

                            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                            {
                                Nume.Text = resultString;
                            });

                            // Continue listening
                            Listen();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ioEx)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show($"I/O Error: {ioEx.Message}"));
                    isListening = false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show($"Unexpected Error: {ex.Message}"));
                    isListening = false;
                }
            }, null);
        }


        private void startButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                mySerialPort.PortName = "COM4";
                mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
                mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

                mySerialPort.Open();
                isListening = true;

                Listen();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong!");
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried to check on Arduino IDE and the arduino gives on good data. I also tried to to the "ReceiveData" old function and it works. I just don't get it why it doesn't work anymore. I also tried older version of my app (from what I commited before my changes) and it still doesn't work. I have no ideea anymore.

Did a windows update also update the dotnet runtime on the machine? The port itself is good? (Hardware, I mean) Does the program work on a different machine?

@Fildor I updated the Io.Port nugget when I saw the error to v9 and the .net framework to 8 and I still receive it. The port is good, as I said in the post, I see the information via Serial Monitor on Arduino IDE and the program doesn't work anymore on another pcs. I will try on a third tomorrow morning.

I probably missed it before but the sync function (ReceiveData) is working, just the async Begin/EndReceive do not? That's weird.

@Fildor yes, it works, and the funny thing is that sometimes, when I put it on debug mod, it works, but in compiled mode it never works..

Oh, ... that would push me in the direction of some sort of timing and/or threading problem. (aka racing condition)

Do not listen for data on UI thread. Make a dedicated thread for this. Also verify if only this one application is accessing this port at the same time.

@Sinus32 I verified in the resource monitor, the COM is being used only when I start reading in my app..also, the code used to work perfectly, but all of a sudden it doesn't work anymore. I tried 3 different laptops, old commits, no ideea..
